# Dragging an image on canvas flashing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag an image around on my canvas but in doing so I have an issue where once the image is in negative coordinates I get a condition where its

```
mouseX - negativeImageCoords // 200 - minus 210 = 410
```

making my image jump around like a popcorn kitten on the canvas, not the desired effect.

Here is my code and I'm hoping it's something stupid and I can put this down to being tired..

```
function (e) {
    var
        // The mouse x and y positions
        mx = e.offsetX,
        my = e.offsetY,

        // The last known position
        lx = cache.lx, // These are from a JSON object
        ly = cache.ly; 

    // The temporary image
    var img = $('#loadedImage');

    // Get the image context
    var canvas_context = this.mask(); 

    cache.lx = (mx - lx);
    cache.ly = (my - ly);

    console.log(mx, lx);
    console.log(my, ly);        

    // Redraw
    canvas_context.drawImage(img.get(0), cache.lx, cache.ly, img.width(), img.height());
}
```

here is the mask function (included in case it is the perpetrator..

```
function () {
    var mask_name = 'circle';
    var context = ctx.context();
    var mask;
    var isSameMask = false;
    var composition = 'lighter';

    // Add a check to see if it's the same mask
    if (cache.mask && cache.mask.src) {
        if (cache.mask.src !== 'images/masks/' + mask_name + '.png') {
            isSameMask = false;
        }
    }

    // If we don't have a cached mask, load it and cache it
    if (!cache.mask && !isSameMask) {
        // Create a new mask
        mask = new Image;

        // Draw when its loaded
        mask.onload = function () {
            //ctx.clear();
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            context.globalCompositeOperation = composition;
        };

        mask.src = 'images/masks/' + mask_name + '.png';
        // Set the cache as this new mask
        cache.mask = mask;

        imageEvents.size(0);
    } else {
        ctx.clear();
        // It's cached, so just redraw it
        context.drawImage(cache.mask, 0, 0);
        context.globalCompositeOperation = composition;
    }

    return context;
}
```

Why is the image jumping around?

It has to be noted that I have thrown this together for an appjs project, any help/advice from you all is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, managed to get this working. The fix was updating the cached image positions on mousedown and just adding the cached positions to the mouse positions. Here is the code:

```
function drag (e) { // :void
    var
        // The mouse x and y positions
        mx = e.offsetX,
        my = e.offsetY,

        // The last known position
        lx = mx+cache.lx,
        ly = my+cache.ly;

    // The temporary image
    var img = $('#loadedImage');

    // Get the image context
    var canvas_context = this.mask();

    cache.ix = lx;
    cache.iy = ly;

    // Redraw
    canvas_context.drawImage(img.get(0), lx, ly, img.width(), img.height());
    textEvents.draw();
}
```

And my down events

```
    cache.ix = 0;
    cache.iy = 0;

    // Listen for a mousedown or touchstart event
    canvas.on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
        cache.lx = cache.ix - e.offsetX;
        cache.ly = cache.iy - e.offsetY;
        // Add a move listener
        canvas.on('mousemove touchmove', function (e) {
            that.drag.call(that, e);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks buddy :) I will do once it lets me, in 6 hours

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide an answer without seeing the code in action but could it be those conditions you specify, e.g.:

```
if (lx < 0) {
    cache.lx = (mx + lx);
} else {
    cache.lx = (mx - lx);
}
```

Surely you don't want to change the sums if `lx` is less or more than `0`. Just let the maths do its job. Mathematically:

`mx + -1` is the same as `mx - 1`

`mx + +1` is the same as `mx + 1`

`mx - -1` is the same as `mx + 1` [double negative]

That would be why '200 - minus 210 = 410'; that's actually correct.

**EDIT**

The variable `lx` is the cached (therefore old) position; `mx` is the new position.

Therefore `lx - mx` will return the difference between the cached and the new position, which I think (if I understand you correctly) is what you want to move your image by a certain amount. Same for `ly - my`.

When it comes to caching the new mouse positions, surely you just want to cache the current ones, e.g.

```
cache.lx = mx; // current position cached for future reference
```

Caching the difference or a summation will just add to the confusion (again, if I've understood what you're trying to do).

Comment: I have tried not modifying the math, that was just a desperate attempt and stopping it from hopping about.

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer in case it helps.

Comment: The cache only stores the last know positions (l = last, lx, ly)

So using mx will not move the image, the image needs to be able to extend out of the canvas' edges (hence the negative positions) but once it's getting into those figures the double negative is causing a positive number and as you're dragging you get a flash as it jumps between positive and negative coordinates.